# RewriteRule of subdirectory gets ignored, L present

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I'm out of solutions here after over a week of tries and errors.
I'm looking to add a GET parameter to an URL as a rewrite, if the actual rewrite contains an additional value. For example: `/foo` should redirtect to index.php?p=test1 and `/foo/bar`should add a second GET argument, let's name it `test` so it gets `index.php?p=test1&test=something`.

My current not working set if the following:

```
RewriteRule ^/?acadie/lisette/?$ index.php?p=contact_single&id=531&ID_AGENT=1380 [QSA,L,S=1]
RewriteRule ^/?acadie/?$ index.php?p=contact_single&id=531 [QSA,L]
```

If I add `RewriteRule .* - [F]` before the second statement, it successfully got 403, so I assume my rule is just ignored at all. If I reverse them, same.
What I'm doing wrong?

I'm running Apache 2.4.29

Comment: for the above rules, what is the request you are using to test them, and what exactly happens when you try?

Comment: I solved the problem by myself, the problem was a bug in Apache so our team updated the server and it works just fine.